# Restore xkb layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I was swapping caps and escape with the following command:

```
setxkbmap -layout de -option caps:swapescape
```

Is there an option for reverting back to the original state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the XKB option you set, you can use `-option` without an argument:

```
setxkbmap -option
```